# How can I see the list of my own answers only for bounty questions?

Tags: support, answers, search, bounties

Is there a possible way to search my own answers that are posted only for bounty questions (whether or not they currently have a bounty on them)?

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard, Actually i need get the list of My Own Answers that are posted to some others bounty questions.

Comment: Not possible, and the one linked to includes this as well. So I don't think there's a point asking for "minified" version of that request. If we'll have bounty search operator, we'll be able to find our own answer for bounty questions easily.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard, i think in that link mentioned the advance search criteria for Featured tab, but a i need to filter user Answers list. Is there any way for that?

Comment: [here is a SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/790732?UserId=5366015)